# How to select all fields of a document and a new property

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to add a new property to the projection of a query using: `select *, 4 Type from c`, but it fails with error `Syntax error, incorrect syntax near ','`. Trying `select c.*, 4 Type from c` results in a similar error: `Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '*'.`

Projecting all properties manually is not really an option as not all documents contain all properties (one of the best features of DocumentDb).

How can I do so?

**UPDATE**

What I am trying to accomplish is something very simple in any SQL Like language. Open any relational database of your choosing and execute `select *, 4 Type from [Table]` and the results are very straight forward: a table with all it's columns and it's corresponding values plus an additional column named `Type` with all rows having the same value: `4`. The difference here is that in a relational database with schema all rows in the database contain the same columns, so it is easy to enumerate the columns instead of asking for `*`. In a schemaless environment like documentdb you can't enumerate them because there could be unlimited combinations.

I am trying to accomplish the same thing that `select c.id, 4 Type from c` accomplishes, but with all properties

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain your intended query and results (including some sample data)? I don't understand your syntax (the `4 Type` part doesn't make sense).

Comment: I'm far from experienced with azure cosmos DB but the select statement doesn't look right. The * means all fields so what is the , 4 type?

Comment: @perfo read update above.

Comment: @DavidMakogon it totally make sense, try running the following query against any collection in documentdb: `select c.id, 4 Type from c`

Comment: @Jonas. As I learnt something from your update it appears that I'm out of my knowledge zone and thus can't help. Sorry mate, good luck with your solution hunting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this issue by adding a User Defined Function:

```
function AddType (c, v) { 
   c['Type'] = v;
   return c;
}
```

and calling it `SELECT value udf.AddType(c,4) FROM c`.

Of course you could make this a little more generic by passing in an array instead, but hopefully the Cosmos Db team will add native support for it.

**WARNING**

This function adds overhead and in our internal tests it more than doubled the RUs. `select * from c` resulted in 90 RUs vs 220 RUs using the function above.